# Django: better (simpler) migration system alternative?

Tags: django, django-migrations

Is there an alternative to built-in Django migration system, which doesn't try to be intelligent?

Ideally, I would like the following:

- Simple DSL for typical operations (add/change/remove column, add/change/remove table, add/change/remove index, etc., including raw SQL as the last resort)
- Auto-revert for these operations (unless raw SQL is used)
- Single folder with all migrations for the whole project (so when I refactor some 'app', e.g. split it into two apps, that doesn't require to change migrations). No boilerplate for specifying migration dependencies: each migration is assumed to depend on every preceding one.
- No 'state' management. Just run the DSL statements.

Comment: no. there isn't